# O notation and o notation

Tags: big-o, little-o

If `f(n) = Θ(g(n))` then I know `f(n)` = `O(n)` and `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`， then I would say there should exist c1 and c2 ≥ 0, n1 ≥ 0, for all n > n1, there exists `c1*g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c2*g(n)`.

Prove `f(n) = c*g(n) + o(g(n))` for some c > 0. My point is `f(n) ≤ c2*g(n)` ==> we have `f(n) < c2*g(n) + c*g(n) ==> fn ≤ c2*g(n) < (c2 + c)*g(n)`. Hence, I would like to say `f(n) = c*g(n) + O(g(n))` is correct for some c > 0. Is that correct?

And can I also say `f(n) = cg(n) + o(g(n))`, for some c > 0?

Comment: StackOverflow is for getting help with specific programming problems, not for computer science homework.

Comment: @GovindParmar I disagree - I think that this is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `f(n) = Θ(g(n))` then I know `f(n) = O(n)` and `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`.

Well, absolutely not. Look, when `f(n) = Θ(g(n))` it means that `f(n)` is a set of functions that grow asymptotically not faster than `g`. When `g` is `n^2`, `f(n)` becomes a set of functions that grow not faster than `n^2` which definitelly isn't  equal to a set of functions that grow not faster than `n^2`. It's because there exists an element which is in in the second set and is not it the first one. It's `h(n) = n^2`.

*Quod erat demonstrandum*